# Powerpoint VBA - How to modify code to loop properly?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following loop, which is meant to create a triangle on slides 2 to 4.

```
For i = 2 To 4

With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

    Dim tri As Shape
    Set tri = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, 886, 0, 74, 74)

End With
Next i
```

The code works, but because I'm calling `ActiveWindow`, the loop creates the triangle 3 times on the same slide (the one I run the macro from) rather than on 3 slides.

I know this is the problem, but I don't know how to modify that part of the code to fix it. What is required instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the iterated presentation slide:

```
For i = 2 To 4

  With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

    Dim tri As Shape
    Set tri = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, 886, 0, 74, 74)

  End With

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

fast solution

```
For i = 2 To 4

With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

    Dim tri As Shape
    Set tri = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, 886, 0, 74, 74)

End With
Next i
```